# Change WndProc of the window

Tags: c++, winapi, button, wndproc

I try to change standart `WndProc` function. I have this code:

```
HWND btn = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"BUTTON", L"Window title", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON
    , 50, 50, 50, 50, (HWND)XApplicationMainWindow->window->_wnd, (HMENU)123,
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(XApplicationMainWindow->window->_wnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);

SetWindowLongPtrW(btn, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassWindowProc);
```

I can use `L"BUTTON"` class name, but when I change `WndProc` function I'll have a problem.[image]

On this picture, you can see the blank square and normal button. If I try to create new `WNDCLASS or WNDCLASSEX`, I'll have nothing... Why?

How can I change the standart `WndProc` function, if I use `L"BUTTON"` class name?

It's my second `WndProc`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:

        //Event click
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case 123:
            OutputDebugStringA("Subclass click2");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at first you need cal not `DefWindowProc` but previous wndproc, which returned by `SetWindowLongPtrW`, then you need pass all messages to it which you not handle special, `WM_CREATE` for example. and finally - for what change button proc at all

Comment: [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).

Comment: [Using `SetWindowSubclass()` is safer than using `SetWindowLongPtr()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefWindowProc()` is the wrong window procedure for your `SubclassWindowProc()` to be calling.

You need to call the *previous* window procedure that you are replacing - the window procedure that handles all of the button's default behaviors (like drawing the button so it actually looks like a button, and responding to user input like a button, etc).  `SetWindowLongPtr()` returns a pointer to that procedure to you, but you are currently ignoring it.

See [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) on MSDN for more details.

Try this instead:

```
WNDPROC btnWndProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            //Event click
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 123:
                    OutputDebugStringA("Subclass click2");
                    break;
            }

            break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(hWnd, btnWndProc, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

...

HWND btn = CreateWindowEx(...);

btnWndProc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtrW(btn, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)SubclassWindowProc);
```

Alternatively, using [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass), which is [safer than using `SetWindowsLongPtr()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883), eg:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, SubclassWindowProc, uIdSubclass);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            //Event click
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 123:
                    OutputDebugStringA("Subclass click2");
                    break;
            }

            break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

...

HWND btn = CreateWindowEx(...);

SetWindowSubclass(btn, SubclassWindowProc, 1, 0);
```

Now, that being said, your subclass will never call `OutputDebugStringA()`, because it will never receive the `WM_COMMAND` message you are expecting.  When a button is clicked, a `WM_COMMAND` message is not sent to the button itself.  The button posts a `WM_COMMAND` message to the button's *parent window* instead (in this case, to `XApplicationMainWindow->window->_wnd`).  So, you need to handle the `WM_COMMAND` message in the window procedure of the *parent window*, not in the window procedure of the button itself.

Otherwise, if you still want to subclass the button itself, you will have to handle the `WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP)` and `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)`/`WM_CHAR` messages that the button receives and then subsequently translates into a `WM_COMMAND` message for its parent window.

Comment: I used ```DefSubclassProc()``` and ```WM_LBUTTONDOWN``` in ```SubclassWindowProc()```. It's working.